# Delete Column Loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I loop through the Sheet via While, so when I find the string "Out" in the first row I delete the row.
The problem is that when I delete that column the next one goes to the deleted position and thus the loop will pass and wont delete it.

Can you help me?

Thanks

```
Sub DeleteCol()

xx = 37
Do While Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, xx) <> ""

Agrup = Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, xx)
Rubri = Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, xx)
If Agrup = "Out" Then
    'Worksheets("Data").Columns(xx).Clear
    Worksheets("Data").Columns(xx).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
End If
xx = xx + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a `For` Loop and loop backwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When deleting rows or columns you always need to loop backwards. Otherwise the current row/column position changes during delete.

This is because deleting always affects the position of rows/columns **after** the current row/column but not before. Therefore looping backwards does not affect our loop because un-processed rows/columns are **before** current row/column which are **not** affected by deleting.

```
Option Explicit 'very first line to ensure all variable are declared

Public Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Data") 'define worksheet

    Dim Argup As Range, Rubri As Range
    Dim iCol As Long, lCol As Long 'iteration column, last column
    Const fCol = 37 'first column

    With ws '<-- use With statement
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'find last used column

        For iCol = lCol To fCol Step -1 'loop from last column backwards to column 37
            Agrup = .Cells(1, iCol)
            Rubri = .Cells(2, iCol)

            If Argup = "Out" Then
                .Columns(iCol).Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
            End If
        Next iCol
    End With

End Sub
```

*I also recommend to declare all variables and always use* `Option Explicit`.

Comment: This can end up easily in an endless loop, if the `lCol` is less than 37. Just noting.

Comment: @Vityata if `lcol` is less than 37 then the loop is run 0 times.

Comment: That's true. VBA is wiser than I thought.

Comment: @Vityata "*VBA is wiser than I thought*" don't trust in that. It's a trap. Most times it is not.

Comment: I usually assume the worst there. That's why I thought it would run endlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already posted, you need to delete from the end, rather than from the begining. But why? Lets image you have five columns, and you want to delete columns 2 and 4. Before deleting, this is how your columns look like:

```
Column index in loop:   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
Original column number: | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

Now you start from the begining...

- Index 1: Do nothing (as intended)
- Index 2: **Delete** (as intended)

Let's pause for a minute. Now let us see how deleting column 2 changed the picture:

```
                        Loop direction ---->
Column index in loop:   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
Original column number: | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

Now you might see that something is wrong. But lets continue the loop for the sake of the example:

- Index 3: Do nothing (but this was originally column 4, and should have been deleted)
- Index 4: **Delete** (but this was originally column 5, and should **NOT** have been deleted)
- Index 5: Do nothing (depending on your code, you might get and out of bounds error)

Lets try to go backwards instead, maybe that helps:

- Index 5: Do nothing (as intended)
- Index 4: **Delete**

Let us pause, once again, to see how it looks now

```
                        <---- Loop direction
Column index in loop:   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
Original column number: | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
```

Well, something did shift. But as the next step in the loop is 3 (and we are going backwards), it doesn't really matter. Hope that helps the understanding a bit :-)